# retrieve single row in LARAVELusing eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

i am using laravel 5.1 and want to retrieve a single row in the database then manipulate it after.

my current code is

```
$profiles = Profile::where('user_id', $this->user->user_id)
->where('profile_code', $this->user->profile_code)
->get();

foreach($profiles as $profile ){
$data['address'] = $profile->address;
}
```

why cant i do it like this?

```
$profiles = Profile::where('user_id', $this->user->user_id)
->where('profile_code', $this->user->profile_code)
->get();

$data['address'] = $profiles->address;
```

am i using a wrong function or something?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data['address'] = $profiles[0]->address;
```

When you are using `get()`, it returns an array of Std class object.

In addition to retrieving all of the records for a given table, you may also retrieve single records using `first`. Instead of returning a collection of models, these methods return a single model instance:

```
// Retrieve the first model matching the query constraints...
$flight = App\Flight::where('active', 1)->first();
```

Comment: so there is no other way for me to use this kind of declaration?
$data['address'] = $profiles->address;

Comment: You have to loop by using foreach() and then you can use it like $data['address'] = $profiles->address;

Comment: ok i just thought there is a function that can retrieve a single row in the db then retrieve data without using for each. so i still need to use foreach even when retrieving a single row. thanks men

Comment: If you know its a single row then you can use it like **$profiles[0]->address;**

Answer (score 0):

**laravel 5.8**

Retrieving A Single Row / Column From Profile

If you just need to retrieve a single row from the database table, you may use the `first()` method. This method will return a single stdClass object:

```
$Profile = DB::table('Profiles')->where('user_id', $this->user->user_id)
->where('profile_code', $this->user->profile_code)->first();
```

If you don't even need an entire row, you may extract a single value from a record using the `value()` method. This method will return the value of the column directly:

```
$address = DB::table('Profiles')->where('user_id', $this->user->user_id)
->where('profile_code', $this->user->profile_code)->value('address');
```